# java encoding in rest header

Tags: c#, java, web-services, rest, encoding

I am using java 6 on tomcat in intelij as a server, and I have a C# client that sends requests to the java server, the request can have characters like ǵ in the **header** values.

in one of the java filters that looks like :

```
 public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws IOException, ServletException
    {
 String str=request.getHeader(HEADER_NAME);
```

I get a header value that is sent from the c# app with a character

ǵ  http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f5/index.htm

but in java it looks like

õ  http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/f5/index.htm

or ??

how can I make sure that java gets the header in the correct encoding , i.e I want to see ǵ in java.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's a way to specify the encoding for header values.

Do you have control of the client? You'll need to either make sure it encodes the headers using Tomcat's default (which may be system-dependent) or use MIME encoding on both sides (probably safest).

Comment: Http uses 8859-1 for "free text" header field values. Text of other encodings must use MIME encoding according to rfc 2047.